# Websocket Servlet thread-safe

Tags: multithreading, servlets, thread-safety, websocket

I'am playing around with WebSocketServlet (tomcat) and I have some question about doing it properly without race condition problems.

I have an instance variable (so non thread-safe) that will keep track of all the websocket connections

```
HashMap<String,MyServers> myNonThreadSafeVariable = HashMap<String,MyServers>
```

This is what the HashMap will contain (roughly...)

```
private final class MyServers extends MessageInbound {
       final Set<MyClients> clients = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<MyClients>();
       private String serverName; 

      @Override
      protected void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) {}

      @Override
      protected void onClose(WsOutbound outbound) {}

      @Override
      protected void onText(WsOutbound outbound) {}
}

private final class Clients extends MessageInbound {

       private int clientID; 


      @Override
      protected void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) {}

      @Override
      protected void onClose(WsOutbound outbound) {}

      @Override
      protected void onText(WsOutbound outbound) {}
}
```

So now.. during my servlet life time, I am looping through **myNonThreadSafeVariable** and then maybe also will loop through **myNonThreadSafeVariable.clients** and then maybe also modified or add a **clients** or **server** etc...

For example when a server connect, in his onOpen there will be something like

```
myNonThreadSafeVariable.put(key,this);
```

or When a client connects in his onOpen (quit concern about this one)

```
server = myNonThreadSafeVariable,get(key);
sever.clients.add(this);
```

Or sometimes when I have to ping all the clients of all the servers:

```
for (Entry<String, MyServers> entry : myNonThreadSafeVariable.entrySet()) {

   MyServers server = entry.getValue();
   server.sendMessage("ping||");

   for (MyClients member : entry.getValue().clients) {
      client.sendMessage("")
   }
}
```

So If I undertand  correctly as myNonThreadSafeVariable is global so will myNonThreadSafeVariable.clients etc..

So my question is what is a good practice to avoid race condition in this scenario ?

Using mutex and synchronized on them when access ether the myNonThreadSafeVariable and myNonThreadSafeVariable.clients ? Or should I avoid using an instance variable at all ? But how ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **[ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)**: you block readers and writers when writing, you block only writers when reading:

```
private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private final Lock readLock = lock.readLock();
private final Lock writeLock = lock.writeLock();
...
writeLock.lock();
try
{
    myNonThreadSafeVariable.put(key,this);
}
finally
{
    writeLock.unlock();
}
...
writeLock.lock();
try
{
    server = myNonThreadSafeVariable,get(key);
    sever.clients.add(this);
}
finally
{
    writeLock.unlock();
}
...
readLock.lock();
try
{
    for (Entry<String, MyServers> entry : myNonThreadSafeVariable.entrySet())
    {
        MyServers server = entry.getValue();
        server.sendMessage("ping||");

        for (MyClients member : entry.getValue().clients)
        {
            client.sendMessage("")
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    readLock.unlock();
}
```

Moreover if you want to avoid the read lock you can **copy the whole collection** and scan the copy, letting the possibility for the original collection to be changed while notifying.